# How i can save the id for an object added to an object store to use after?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to know how I can save the id for an object added to an object store?

I know I can get the id with the `request.result` of the `onsuccess` function but I want to save like this:

```
//after a get
var id;
request.onsuccess = function(event){
    id = request.result.id;
}
alert(id); //undefined
```

I have seen another answers and all say how to show the id in the `onsuccess` function:

```
request.onsuccess = function(event){
    alert(request.result.id);
}
```

but I want to save the `id` to use outside the `onsuccess`.

Comment: The other answers say how to show the id in the `onsuccess` because *that's the answer*. You simply can not use it in the place where your `alert()` is. Study the information in the duplicate until you understand the coding patterns you should use.

Comment: Yes, @squint is right. You cann't use response in a variable. There is an other way to do it. Store response value in a hidden field on form and then on alert call that id. like document.getElementById(<id value>).value = request.result.id; and then  alert(document.getElementById(<id value>).value); only if response code is 200

Comment: Thanks, i will study the information.
And i want the id because has an autoincrement value and it is added aotumatically.

Comment: More specifically, the generated key will simply not be known until the asynchronous operation has completed. There could be other transactions or requests happening that will generate new keys.